# Use of conditional function, condition in definition

Tags: if-statement, definition

I have a seemingly trivial problem. I write a definition and I don't know how to introduce conditional functions.

I have a definition that works:

```
def function_1 (kot):
     if kot == True:
         print ("Yes:")
     else:
         print ("NO:")
```

It wokrs good

```
function_1 (False)
```

No:

or

```
function_1 (True)
```

Yes:

But I would like to have such a thing in my definition

```
def function_1 (kot = True):
     if kot == True:
         print ("Yes:")
     else:
         print ("NO:")
```

and it doesn't work any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you need to call the function as you did in the above example

```
def function_1 (kot=True):
 if kot == True:
     print ("Yes:")
 else:
     print ("NO:")

function_1()
```

output:

```
Yes:
```